# Browser not seeing a media query

Tags: media-queries

I have a page with several media queries. All but one of them work. I can't figure out why in the chrome inspector it is not seeing my media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1530px) {
#title-1 {
top: 600px;}}
```

I have a total of 6 media queries:

```
max-width 1530px
max-width 1024px
max-width 899px
max-width 699px
max-width 499px
max-width 375px
```

All but the `1530px` work.

That would be the About APCO link. Seen here: http://www.starqualityair.com/uv-lamps.php

Answer (score -1):

never mind it has decided to work. must of been a cache issue